# ReactJS onClick not working on first element in menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, components

I'm making a custom dropdown list in reactjs. When I click on any element in the dropdown list I get it's value and put it inside an input and it works just fine. The problem is that the first element returns nothing and I can't get it's value. Also I developed the dropdown list to disappear when I choose any element inside of it. But like I said it works just fine on all elements except the first one.

I solved the problem by setTimeOut and hide the dropdown list in 50 milliseconds. But I don't think this's a right solution.

```
//Select Component
class Select extends Component {
  showList = (e) => {
    e.target.closest('.select').classList.add('active');
  }

  hideList = (e) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      e.target.closest('.select').classList.remove('active');
    }, 100);
  }

  selectValue = (e) => {
    let value = e.target.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;
    this.setState({ selectValue: value })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <input
        {...this.props}
        type="text"
        placeholder={this.props['placeholder']}
        onFocus={this.showList}
        onBlur={this.hideList}
        value={this.state.selectValue}
        onChange={this.changeSelectValue}
        required
      />
      <div className="select">

        <div className="select-options menu full-width">
          {
            this.props.list.map(element => {
              return (
                <MenuItem text={element} onClick={(e) => this.selectValue(e)} />
              )
            })
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

==================

```
class MenuItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <p className={"menu-item " + this.props['type'] } {...this.props}>
        {this.props['icon'] ? <i className={this.props['icon']} ></i> : null}
        <span>{this.props['text']}</span>
      </p>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1.use key prop for every MenuItem Component when you are using the list to create a list of MenuItems.
2.Instead of getting value from target in selectValue function directly pass the value from onClick handler.

```
selectValue = (e , element) => {
   this.setState({ selectValue: element })
}

<MenuItem text={element} key={element} onClick={(e) => this.selectValue(e , element)} />
```

Editted:-
Remove the onBlur handler and put the functionality of hideList inside selectValue function after setState,you can use setState with callback if normal setState doesn't work

```
selectValue = (e) => {
    let value = e.target.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;
    this.setState({ selectValue: value })
    e.target.closest('.select').classList.remove('active');

  }
```

Comment: Same problem but nice idea to get values

Comment: Check the latest edit,i think that would resolve your problem